# Where does OPFS with SQLite WASM store files for the chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome-extension, path, origin-private-file-system

Simple but deceptively difficult question:

I got what I was trying to get working here: [Using OPFS (Origin Private FileSystem) with SQLite WASM in background.js Chrome Extention (Worker is not defined error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77420183/using-opfs-origin-private-filesystem-with-sqlite-wasm-in-background-js-chrome?noredirect=1#comment136490384_77420183)

But, I can't seem to find where the .sqlite3 file is stored?

I have tried `sudo find / -type f -name "mydb.sqlite3"` and `sudo find / -type f -name "*.sqlite3"` searching the entire computer for the file but it doesn't seem to be found.  This tells me I must be missing something fundamental about this?

I know the database is remembering data somehow because I can view the console messages after refreshing the extention and see more and more rows when I read the database.

I have tried the OPFS extention to try viewing the database but that doesn't work either (refer to screenshot)

[image]

[image]
I feel like a complete idiot that I can't figure out where this file is being stored.  Anyone know? I just want to be able to view it with an SQLite reader and verify everything is storing correctly in an easier manner.  Currently I can query it using SQL commands to verify it works but this is very slow and tedious and I feel unnecessary. In my screenshot it says LIMIT 3, but I can remove that to show all rows just fine just FYI

Comment: OPFS files are private to the origin of the page and not visible to the user like the regular file system. It is a browser specific implementation and there is no one way to find it. Source: https://web.dev/articles/origin-private-file-system#the_user-visible_versus_the_origin_private_file_system

Comment: If this is the case, how do I save the data from the persistant storage to a file? How can I export all the data to an .sqlite3 file? and is it possible to do this automatically? (like as soon as I read the database I can just export it constantly?)

Comment: Use the non-private FS: `showSaveFilePicker`.

Comment: (The sqlite JS/WASM developer here...)

Regarding exporting them, see the docs:


https://sqlite.org/wasm/doc/trunk/cookbook.md#uldl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least going by the spec, OPFS files cannot be located on file system of the operating system. The actual storage of files and their location is implementation details of browser.

from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Origin_private_file_system):

> Browsers persist the contents of the OPFS to disk somewhere, but you cannot expect to find the created files matched one-to-one. The OPFS is not intended to be visible to the user.

If you want to export file, you need to write code for reading the file from OPFS & download on to user's file system (on some event, like click of a button). However, OPFS file can't be automatically sync'ed  with a file on the OS file system

Comment: Yours was the solution I ultimately went with, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that what I'm going to tell you is an implementation detail of Chrome that could change at any time, but at the time of this writing, this approach works on macOS, the platform you're using according to the screenshots. In the console (not the DevTools console, the actual system console), enter the following command, customizing the `"some unique string you know is in the OPFS file"` part:

```bash
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File\ System -type f -exec grep -q "some unique string you know is in the OPFS file" {} \; -print
```

On macOS, all OPFS files are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System`, but the problem is locating the file you're interested in, since the file names don't correspond to the file names the developer used in their OPFS code and the folder names don't correspond to the origins. A little `grep` magic and knowledge about the file contents to the rescue…

Comment: I knew it was stored somewhere haha, I found a solution around this in the meantime, but it's good to know it's actually stored somewhere!